# How do I get autochdir to work on a Mac when running Vim from the terminal?

Tags: macos, vim

In MacVim `autochdir` works without a problem. However, lately I've been running iTerm2 (full screen with split) for coding and the lack of `autochdir` is really bothering me. Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: You can replace the terminal Vim with MacVim. Create a symlink that points to the mvim script like this: `ln -s /path/to/mvim /path/to/some/bin/vim` See `:help mvim` for other tips on that.

Comment: Another option (the one I use) is to use MacVim's own CLI `vim` executable instead of Mac OS X's default with this alias in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`: `alias vim='/path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "the lack of `autochdir`"? It works fine both in CLI and in GUI.

If you have `set autochdir` in your `~/.vimrc` this feature will work the same way whether you are in MacVim or iTerm2 or Terminal or whatever.

But I suspect you are changing dirs in an iTerm2 split and expecting Vim to somehow learn about that change and change its `pwd` accordingly. Am I right? "Unfortunately" Vim doesn't know about the second iTerm2 split and can't react to your `cd` there.

Comment: Sorry, my description wasn't very clear. I get the error `E518: Unknown option: autochdir` when I run Vim in the terminal, and no issue with MacVim. I also don't get this error when running Vim in the terminal on Linux. I made the jump to assuming that the Mac OS version of Vim didn't support this command for some reason.

Comment: Yes Mac OS X's default Vim sucks, it's old and compiled with a very small feature set. See my comment above for a quick and solid workaround or El Isra's comment for using MacVim instead of Vim.

Comment: I ended up going with the MacVim alias. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tick but my answer is totally useless. El Isra should expand on is comment and make it a proper answer.

Comment: True. Once he does I'll change the check.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

```
> which vim
```

If it says `/usr/bin/vim`, you're using the mac base installation. This is an old version of vim and doesn't support `autochdir`. You'll need a newer version.

Check if you have another installation of vim by running:

```
> /usr/local/bin/vim
```

If so, add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin`

If not, install it:

```
> brew install vim
```